# Access website by ipaddress

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to access websites via the ip address rather than http address. I am trying out a number of well know sites such as microsoft and google and getting their ip address by pinging them. For instance 184.87.106.199 is microsoft and 216.58.221.68 is google.

```
    async Task<HttpStatusCode> RequestPage(string url, HttpClient client) {
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage();

        try {
            var response = await client.GetAsync("http://" + url);

            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} - {1}", url, response.StatusCode.ToString()));

            return response.StatusCode;
        } catch (TaskCanceledException) {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} - Timeout", url));

            return HttpStatusCode.GatewayTimeout;
        }
    }
```

However it does not appear to work for every site. google works fine if i request http://216.58.221.68 but microsoft returns a bad request status.

what am i missing?

Comment: Well, the first one given is not working in browser as well, so I guess it may be problem with address.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot reliably visit a website based on the IP address. Often a server is configured to host multiple websites on a single IP address, and based on the URL it will serve the correct website.

Answer (score 2):

When you make an HTTP request to a website with your browser, the browser itself will do the lookup for IP address and then connect. However, your browser will send something like this:

```
GET http://stackoverflow.com/ HTTP/1.1
Host: stackoverflow.com
```

This means the remote end knows which website to send you to as the server could be hosting many sites, particularly in a shared hosting environment.

Also, to complicate matters even further, some websites will have multiple IP address.